# is it possible to install 64 bit ubuntu ios on 32 bit windows 7 ?

Tags: system-installation

i need help from you. i do not know, whether i can install 64 bit Ubuntu ions on my laptop with 32 bit windows 7 and my laptop got Intel core 3 and  3 GB Ram.

Comment: Probably yes, if you mean Ubuntu installation. But your question isn't clear enough (I didn't understand what does "Ubuntu ions" mean). I recommend you to try Ubuntu on your laptop by booting it from Live-USB or Live-DVD (you can just boot and try using it).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a 64 bit system yes, if you have a 32 bit system, no.  When you try the install the 64 bit system, your program will say that your system doesn't have the capacity and will abort the install. The 32 bit edition is identical to the 64 bit system except that it is designed for 32 bit computers.  64 bit systems can handle large files or large amounts of files better, which could be very important if you spend a lot of time sorting pictures, for example.  If you did succeed in craming a 64 bit install into a 32 bit system, it wouldn't really give you the advantages of a 64 bit system.  If your issue is speed, Lubuntu runs faster because it is lighter.  To a degree, that is also true of Ubuntu Mate.  I don't know the other desktops well enough to say.  A few years ago Ubuntu told people that if you didn't know if you were at all unsure, just install the 32 bit version.  If your system isn't getting the job done for you, try Lubuntu.